# QuartzCore PDFKit

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, pdfkit, quartz-core

So basically I'm trying to count the pages of a PDF, but I'm having a little trouble... I imported QuartzCore in order to use PDFKit to count the pages.

The error I'm getting says `PDFDocument is an unresolved identifier`.

```swift
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class Recht: UIViewController, ENSideMenuDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var pdfView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pdfView.delegate = self

        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(String(lawNumberToPresent), withExtension: "pdf")
        let pdfDoc = PDFDocument(URL: url)
        pdfDoc.pageCount()
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### UPDATE

If your deployment target is iOS 11 or later, you can use PDFKit.

#### ORIGINAL

PDFKit is only available on Mac OS X, not on iOS. You will need to use a third-party framework like [FastPdfKit](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit) or [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/), or write your own PDF parser.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me out.

Comment: PDFKit is now available for iOS11+.